# How to discard the repeating elements of a list

Tags: formatting, filtering, conditional, procedural-programming

Lets say there is a random list of expressions :

```
a={Sin[x], Sin[3 x], Sin[4 x], Sin[x], Sin[4 x], Sin[x], Sin [5 x], Sin[3 x], Sin[5 x]}

Plot[{a}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Is there anyway we can compare the list of expressions and select only one or discard the repeating functions.

so, the final output should be `a={Sin[x], Sin[3 x], Sin[4 x], Sin [5 x]}`

Select does not work if we compare two lists: such as

```
Select[{a}, # == {a}&, 1]
```

or a for loop with continue?

Comment: `DeleteDuplicates` ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Union`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Union.html), which gives a sorted list of all the distinct elements that appear in any of the arguments.

```
Plot[
    Evaluate[Echo@Union@a]
    , {x, 0, 2 Pi}
]
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

My go-to response for this is to do

```
Plot[Evaluate@DeleteDuplicates[a], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

> [image: plot]

Comment: @rhermans what if the functions are different in a list a but the output is same. So, I just want to select the first function with the same output and discard the following one. Union and DeleteDuplicate works perfectly on trignometeric functions (by simplifying), but what if the functions are not trignometeric. However, I can not think of any other example. If you have anything in your mind to sort solve such example.

Comment: @MuhammadAli are you talking about `Sin[x + Pi/2]` and `Cos[x]` for example?

Comment: Mathematica will simplify it to Sin or Cos and then sort it out. I tried this.

Comment: @MuhammadAli `DeleteDuplicates` and `Union` both work in such examples. In more complicated, you can do `a//FullSimplify` or `TrigToExp` or `FunctionExpand` at the level of your list and then you should be good to go

Comment: @MuhammadAli I'm confused now, you accepted the answer and now saying that you have a new requirement? That will grant a new question, I think.

Comment: @rhermans Thank you!! I accept the answer this is just a query.